# How to use Algolia autocomplete with bootstrap tag inputs or similar plugin

Tags: jquery, algolia, bootstrap-tags-input

the following is the working code of algolia autocomplete, please help me how I can use it with the bootstrap tag input plugin or any other similar jquery autocomplete, i tried same with jquery tagit plugin and still couldn't solve it

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Algolia| Autocomplete</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        
<div class="aa-input-container" id="aa-input-container">
    <input type="search" id="tags" class="tags" placeholder="Search with algolia..." name="search"
        autocomplete="off" />
</div>
</div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/autocomplete.js/0/autocomplete.min.js"></script>

    <script>

         (function() {
    let client = algoliasearch('algolia-app-id', 'algolia-app-key');
    let index = client.initIndex('tags');
    let enterPressed = false;
    //initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
    autocomplete('#tags',
        { hint: false }, {
            source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 10 }),
            //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
            displayKey: 'name',
            //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
            templates: {
                //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
                suggestion: function (suggestion) {
                    console.log(suggestion)
                    const markup = `

                        <div class="algolia-details">
                            <span>${suggestion.name}</span>
                        </div>
                    `;

                    return markup;
                },
                empty: function (result) {
                    return 'Sorry, we did not find any results for "' + result.query + '"';
                }
            }
        }).on('autocomplete:selected', function (event, suggestion, dataset) {
           console.log(suggestion);
        })
})();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally here I found a solution

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/algolia.css')}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" integrity="sha512-xmGTNt20S0t62wHLmQec2DauG9T+owP9e6VU8GigI0anN7OXLip9i7IwEhelasml2osdxX71XcYm6BQunTQeQg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <style type="text/css">
    .bootstrap-tagsinput{
      width: 100%;
    }
    .label-info{
      background-color: #17a2b8;

    }
    .label {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: .25em .4em;
      font-size: 75%;
      font-weight: 700;
      line-height: 1;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: baseline;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,
      border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 

        <h2>Stacked form</h2>
        <br>
        <form action="test.php" id="form">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name  </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput">    
            </div>
 


      <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary "> 

    </form>

  </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js" integrity="sha512-VvWznBcyBJK71YKEKDMpZ0pCVxjNuKwApp4zLF3ul+CiflQi6aIJR+aZCP/qWsoFBA28avL5T5HA+RE+zrGQYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/algoliasearch/3/algoliasearch.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
    var client = algoliasearch('app-id', 'app-key');
    var index = client.initIndex('categories');

    $('#name').tagsinput({
      typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'citynames',
        displayKey: 'name',
        valueKey: 'name',
        minLength: 1,

        source:  index.ttAdapter({ "hitsPerPage": 10 }),
        templates: {
                //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
                suggestion: function (suggestion) {
                  console.log(suggestion)
                  const markup = `

                  <div class="algolia-details">
                  <span>${suggestion.name}</span>
                  </div>
                  `;

                  return markup;
                } 
            }
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```